# Cant get the tag 'rel' via beautifulsoup webscraping python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to test a beautifulsoup4 webscrape code on a website. Have done most of it but one attribute information due to its location is little tricky for me to accomplish.

Code goes like this:

```
span class="callseller-description-icon">
<a id="phone-lead" class="callseller-description-link" rel="0501365082" href="#">Show Phone Number</a>
```

I am trying this but not sure if its okay

```
try:
        phone=soup.find('a',{'id':'phone-lead'})
        for a in phone:
            phone_result= str(a.get_text('rel').strip().encode("utf-8"))
        print "Phone information:", phone_result
    except StandardError as e:
        phone_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
        print phone_result
```

What is possibly my mistake. It kinda hard to get the `rel` information which has phone numbers

The error i m getting is

```
NavigableString object has no attribute get_text
```

Comment: What output are you getting? Are you sure that `#phone-lead` is not being entered by javascript?

Comment: Error was 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: `.find()` returns one element, why are you iterating it?

Comment: The output can be more than one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`find`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) returns the element not a list, if you want all `a` tags, use  the [`find_all`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) method. Also to get the `rel` attribute you need to use the `.get()` method or dictionary lookup. You can also add `rel=True` to get only those "a" tags where with the "rel" attribute.

Demo:

- Using `find()`

  ```
  >>> soup.find('a', {'id': 'phone-lead', 'rel': True}).get('rel')
  ['0501365082']
  ```
- Using `find_all`:

  ```
  >>> for a in soup.find_all('a', {'id':'phone-lead', 'rel': True}):
  ...     print(a['rel'])
  ... 
  ['0501365082']
  ```

To get a list of all "rel" you can use a list comprehensions

```
>>> [rel for rel in a['rel'] for a in soup.find_all('a', {'id':'phone-lead', 'rel': True})]
['0501365082']
```

Comment: It seems like there are more than 6 results for that particular tag. Can I concatenate it all with a comma in it ? because i need to save it in a field in database

Comment: @Panetta use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.join#str.join)

Comment: Why does BeautifulSoup return a list for `rel` instead of just a string?