# Unique list without spliting entries based on spaces in python

Tags: python, python-2.x, beautifulsoup

Here is the CSS I want to scrap

```
<a id="phone-lead" class="callseller-description-link" rel="050 395 7996" href="#">Show Phone Number</a>
```

Purpose:

To get the phone numbers whereever they are in the CSS. (Note, there are multiple instances of this type of phone numbers so i need to extract all and save it in a list)

Here is what I am using:

```
phone_result=[]
try:
    phone_result = soup.find('a', {'id': 'phone-lead', 'rel':True}).get('rel')
    for a in soup.find_all('a', {'id':'phone-lead', 'rel': True}):
        phone_result+=(a['rel'])
    phone_result=str(phone_result)
    print phone_result

    except StandardError as e:
        phone_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
        print phone_result
```

Problems:

1) It doesnt give unique output. I have tried to convert the string into set but it messes up
2) It considers spaces and consider them as different entries of list

Output example:

```
['050', '395', '7996', '050', '395', '7996', '04', '551', '9485', '050', '395', '7996', '050', '395', '7996', '04', '551', '9485', '04', '551', '9485', '050', '395', '7996', '050', '395', '7996', '04']
```

How do I fix it to get something like

```
[0503957996, 045519485]
```

Solution via help here:

```
phone_result=[]
try:
    # phone_result=  soup.find('a', {'id': 'phone-lead', 'rel': True}).get('rel') (REMOVED)
    for a in soup.find_all('a', {'id':'phone-lead', 'rel': True}):
        phone_result.append(','.join(a['rel']))
    phone_result=str(phone_result)

    print phone_result



except StandardError as e:
    phone_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
    print phone_result
```

**Problem:** 
My Output is like this

```
['055,442,4433','055,334,3342']
```

I believe I need to trim the number?

Comment: Is each <a> id same as "phone-lead"?

Comment: Just to clean the question, remove the first `soup.find` other wise you will get it twice. Also, the except has wrong indentation.

Comment: ignore the except identation. its just typo in copy pasting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `a['rel']` returns a list like `['050', '395', '7996']`. So inside you for loop you could do something like:

```
phone_result.append(''.join(a['rel']))
```

note that `list.append` add an element to the end of the list (and does not return anything) while `+` merge two lists

And other thing, remove the first `soup.find('a',...` before the loop otherwise you will get it twice.

Comment: I followed it. It works but it doesnt give duplicates. I think i need to trim it. Any idea?

Comment: The problem is that I need to trim the phone numbers before appending it. like 050 422 0444 gives result as 050,422,0444 as three items of list

Comment: If you have a list of strings (`your_list = ['050','422','0444']`) you can do "".join(your_list) to get the string `'0504220444'`. Is that what you need?

Comment: it is `"".join(your_list)`, not `",".join(your_list)`

Comment: Is there any way to remove the dashes from the number?

Comment: You mean the simple commas? What you have now is a string, which, for a phone number, is the more appropiate (since it may containe +). If you really want an integer you need to cast it: `int(''.join(a['rel']))`

Comment: I dont want integer but want to remove possible dashes if it can be done

Comment: You can do `phone_number.replace("-","")` with whatever character you want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know this library but it seems like you are creating the phone_result list a few times.

```
phone_result = [] #  creating phone_result list  
try:
    phone_result = soup.find('a', {'id': 'phone-lead', 'rel':True}).get('rel') # dont know if this creates a list but phone_result is declared again
for a in soup.find_all('a', {'id':'phone-lead', 'rel': True}): # doesn't look right considering the above  
    phone_result += (a['rel']) #  this takes the existing list and adds a['rel] to it 
phone_result = str(phone_result)
print phone_result
```

Once you have the correct list of phone numbers you can call set on it to get the unique values

Answer (score 0):

You missunderstood my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37520225/3100115). You don't need to use both `find` and `find_all`. Simply use `find_all` if you want to retrieve all descendants that match your filters. And, as I said you need to use `str.join` to join the result.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<a id="phone-lead" class="callseller-description-link" 
     rel="050 395 7996" href="#">Show Phone Number</a>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
phone_result = [','.join(map(str.strip, a.get('rel'))) for a in soup.find_all('a', {'id':'phone-lead', 'rel': True})]
print phone_result
#  ['050,395,7996']
```